# random.choice works, but random.choices(with probabilities) won't show up

Tags: python

So I am pretty new, and wanted to try to do an online casino.
**random.choice[True,False..]** works, but I needed something with probabilities, so I used **random.choices with weight for prob**, but it won't use it in the next stage of the program to check the if, elif.., it just moves to the **'Do you want to view the deposit'** stage. Why does it jump the whole section? **It does not when I use random.choice**

```
import random

result = random.choices([True,False,'Idk'], weights = (70,20,10), k=2)

gamble1 = int(input('Enter your lucky number: '))

if result == True:
    print('You won 50$!')
elif result == False:
    print('You won 100$!')
elif result == 'Idk':
    print('You won 500$!')
 
    
    
answer = input('Would you like to see your winnings deposit(YES/NO): ')    

if answer == ('yes'):
    print(mywin)
elif answer == ('no'):
    print('Alright!')
    
    
answer2 = input('Would you like to play again?(YES/NO): ')

if answer2 == ('yes'):
    pass
elif answer2 == ('no'):
    print('Thanks for playing!')
```

Comment: What do the docs say about what "random.choices" returns?

Comment: Here's a hint: `k=2`

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow~ In a situation like this you should either try to use your debugger to figure out why you aren't entering the logical statements you are expecting. Do you know what `result` is after you `random.choices` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue your code is having is that you're trying to compare a `bool` to a `list`.

In this line, you set the variable `result` to be a list with two entries.

`result = random.choices([True,False,'Idk'], weights = (70,20,10), k=2)`

So, you get two pseudorandom values in a list, and then try to compare the entire list to a `bool`.

`if result == True:`

So, when the code is executing, `result` might look like `['Idk', True]`, and every single condition you've defined fails -- `['Idk', True]` isn't equal to `True`, it isn't equal to `False`, and it isn't equal to `'Idk'`.

As mentioned by other people's comments, you could fix this by changing the conditional statements to say `if result[0]` instead of `if result`.

If you apply that fix, you'll get an output that looks something like this

```
Enter your lucky number: 7
You won 50$!
Would you like to see your winnings deposit(YES/NO): yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "m.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(mywin) NameError: name 'mywin' is not defined
```

Defining `mywin` isn't hard to fix, though. I'd just re-write the section between where you define `gamble1` and `answer` like this

```
# default value, variable is defined, & no need for an "if True"
mywin = 50 

if result[0] == False:
    mywin = 100
elif result[0] == 'Idk':
    mywin = 500

# print the "You won" with the value of mywin inline
print('You won $%d' % mywin )
```

When you run the code, it should look like this, now --

```
Enter your lucky number: 7
You won $50
Would you like to see your winnings deposit(YES/NO): yes
50
Would you like to play again?(YES/NO): yes
```

Comment: Thank you so much, people like you inspire me to learn more!

Answer (score 2):

the correct values for `weights` are `(0.7, 0.2, 0.1)` and `k` is mean the total output you would get in a list type. So even if the `k` is equal to 1 (by default), it still returns the output as a list.

```
>> result = random.choices([True,False,"Idk"], weights=(0.7,0.2,0.1))
>> print(result[0])
>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an index, because `choices` returns a list.

```
result = random.choices([True, False, 'Idk'], weights=(70, 20, 10), k=2)[0]
```

A helpful way to detect such things yourself would be to try to print out `result` so you can see what the variable actually contains.